# Member of Data Member not found VBA

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, the code won't find the `ActiveChart` even though the line before it selects it. How can i fix it?

```
Sub makeChart(myArr As Variant, title As String)
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Sheets("Action Register")
    sht1.Shapes.AddChart.Select

    Set cht = sht.ActiveChart
    With ActiveChart
    .Parent.Top = Range("D20").Top 'Places chart onto specified area
    .Parent.Left = Range("D20").Left
    .Parent.Width = Range("D20:V20").Width
    .Parent.Height = Range("D20:D29").Height

    .ChartType = xlAreaStacked
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Machine"""
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Application.Index(myArr, , 1)
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Application.Index(myArr, , 2)
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Handling"""
    .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Application.Index(myArr, , 3)
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(3).Name = "=""Fiber"""
    .SeriesCollection(3).Values = Application.Index(myArr, , 4)
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(4).Name = "=""Process"""
    .SeriesCollection(4).Values = Application.Index(myArr, , 5)
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(5).Name = "=""Other"""
    .SeriesCollection(5).Values = Application.Index(myArr, , 6) 'Legends and writes in values for graph

    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True 'Labels
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Months"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Rate(m)"
    .ChartArea.Font.Size = 20

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: A worksheet doesn't have an `ActiveChart` property. Just use `ActiveChart` or `Application.ActiveChart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A worksheet doesn't have an `ActiveChart` property. Just use `ActiveChart` or `Application.ActiveChart`.

Answer (score 0):

Right of the top I can see these 2 mistakes

```
Dim sht1 As Sheets <-------- you forgot this (not sht as Worksheet)
Set sht1 = Sheets("Action Register")
sht1.Shapes.AddChart.Select

Set cht = sht.ActiveChart <-------------- you got your naming all wrong here
```

Comment: What is the difference between the dim as Sheets and Worksheets?

Comment: the name (sorry that wasn't clear at all) sht >sht1, also the sheets object can contain charts.